A proposition for Rising the forum participance and presence
On AshRj suggestion I'm reposing my idea from  

How do we increase the number of questions being asked?

I could be wrong but in RE there is a real big gap between experienced and newbies, so what do you think about the following:

To encourage question asking there must be constant problem that people deal with, SO
We can create a section where experienced reversers (but do not have to) give problems to solve (but who ever asks must already know the answer) - like some sort of a challenge and it should be always a hard one. This could be voted by high rank users.
who ever wants to solve this challenge can get back to question section and ask questions to solve the challenge.

I think by this way we will "synthetically" rise the question number and enrich the audience. I'm by myself a sort of newbie and I think exactly from like myself will come new questions, new ideas that even veterans will learn.
Regarding the QnA scheme, IMHO will not really encourage the participation as the question was asked and answered, leaving little place for thinking. Again, its IMHO.
We can re-thing QnA scheme to be more active - like give the answer only in couple of days/hours.

Closing as duplicate because its the same idea, that one got more attention, and it was first suggested by the OP there.

But I am not talking about regular challenges here. If there are so many duplicates, we probably should consolidate all the threads!
